# PowerPoint VBA - hyperlink - change text to display to slide number

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have set up an index for a presentation with hyperlinks to the slide number for each item to go to.  The hyperlink 'text to display' has been manually set to the slide number.  How would I go about updating this item using VBA if I add or remove a slide from the presentation?

Update: I've tried a couple of methods that almost work see this link for a ...

[Mock Up of TOC to be updated](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xedz2mbo414jbul/180226.TOC.Update.pptm.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Are they in order so first hyperlink will always be to slide 3, next will be to slide 4? etc?

Comment: The slides are in order but I'm not looking for an update of every slide - just key slides at the start of each section - I've now attached a mock-up of what I am trying to achieve to the original question including some code that I found at https://blog.thoughtlabs.com/blog/how-to-create-a-semi-automated-table-of-contents-in-powerpoint

Comment: I’ll have a look. Worth noting my earlier attempt didn’t overwrite the hyperlink. I had to check :-) The hyperlinks work in slideshow view.

Comment: Likely my ignorance of setting things up to get the best result - all suggestions appreciated